# To pass Core web vitals you need a website close to amp level

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-development, page-speed, core-web-vitals

So Google is rolling out AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) but increasing the pressure on CWV with new experimental metrics. To pass CWV, you will need to render a page almost identical to amp level.

Do you think is this the right way to go?
Not every company is prepared for this transition?
Did you try to read all the documentation related to CWV?
Developers are unaware of the matter.
As well, industries like eCommerce/news will suffer the most.

CWVs are evolving too fast; I see companies being more reactive than proactive on the changes over CWV, and many won't have the ability to survive the changes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd encourage you to explore the [Core Web Vitals Technology Report](https://cwvtech.report), it shows what percent of websites with particular technologies have good CWV. You can see that most technologies are able to achieve good CWV for some non-trivial number of websites. It may be small (5%+) for some technologies, but it goes to show that it can be done.

For example, here's a look at mobile experiences on the top 10 most popular CMSs:

[image]

All of them have more than 20% of websites with good CWV experiences. Some are as high as 60%! (Some of these sites may be using AMP, but I wouldn't expect that to be a huge factor)

AMP is one way to make a fast website, but certainly not the only way.